# R.color.green showing error while changing background color

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to change background color of textviews, like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
        arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
        if(arrBool[i]==true) {
            textView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkgrey);
        }
    }
```

I am getting error for R.color.darkgrey.
Please help me with this.

Comment: textView[i].setBackgroundResource(getResource().getColor(R.color.darkgrey)); (",)?

Comment: I tried this its says getResource() is undefined??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `getResources()` method and after that call `getColor()` method.

```
textView[i].setBackgroundResource(getResource().getColor(R.color.darkgrey));
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Its not solved yet. Error has gone but when I click, it shows, unfortunately, myapp stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

While using colors in color.xml you must call the [`getResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29) method.

Change your code to

```
for(int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
    arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
    if(arrBool[i]==true) {
        textView[i].setBackgroundResource(getResource().getColor(R.color.darkgrey));
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't made Color.xml. Do it need to create it or it creates automatically?

Comment: ya, if you are using your own custom colors maintain those colors.xml in values folder and call as specified above

Comment: If you want to use android predefined colors then simply call textView[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);

Comment: Thanks, the error has gone but when I click on a button then it shows error as, unfortunately app stopped.

Comment: if you are using color.xml then delete the import android.R;. please check it carefully.

Comment: I am not using Color.xml. I just used android.R.color.black.
It worked for different java file, but not working for the one I wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately, myapp has stopped. What could be the problem

Comment: 10-31 01:09:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):  at com.app.myfirstapp.ParkingLot2.onCreate(ParkingLot2.java:86)
10-31 01:09:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-31 01:09:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-31 01:09:59.586: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, you should probably use if the code is part of an activity.

```
for(int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
    arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
    if(arrBool[i]==true) {
        textView[i].setBackgroundResource(getResource().getColor(R.color.darkgrey));
    }
}
```

Please notice `getResource()` is a method of `ContextWrapper`, use

```
mContext.getResource().getColor(R.color.darkgrey)
```

if needed, where `mContext` is a `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

set background color, if its in color by:

```
textView[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgrey));
```